# v8 build via AUR on Manjaro (Arch Linux) fails - Message: "ERROR: A failure occurred in check()"

Tags: virtualbox, v8, manjaro

While running Manjaro Linux on Oracle's VirtualBox, I've been trying to build v8 through `Pamac` via the AUR repository. But ultimately, after running about 15k or so tests, the whole process always fails with the following error message: `ERROR: A failure occurred in check()`

I looked at the PKGBUILD file, and I found this:

```
check() {
  cd v8
  msg2 "Using `which python`"
  msg2 "Testing, this will also take a while..."
  tools/run-tests.py --no-presubmit \
                     --outdir=out.gn \
                     --buildbot \
                     --arch=$V8_ARCH \
                     --mode=Release
}
```

However, I can't find any obvious errors with my untrained eye, so I'm currently stuck.

How do I get v8 to build on my system?

Comment: You should contact the maintainers of the AUR package. In the meantime, is there a way to simply skip the `check()` step?

Comment: @jmrk: I suppose I could just edit the build file, but I'm not confident enough to try. I'd like to check first if the problem is on my end before contacting the maintainer(s).